# exclude all IP that start w/ X

Tags: exit-relays, node

How to exclude all nodes with IP that start with some number?

Priority for `ExitNodes`, but all it's well too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor allows you to specify `ExcludeNodes` using an address pattern/mask. For example, to exclude all nodes starting with `255.[...]`, you can use `ExcludeNodes 255.0.0.0/8`.

Comment: ths for answer. the /8 at the end what means, is it important?

Comment: @user406126 The `/8` is called a subnet mask and is important if you want to exclude a range of IP addresses. You can read more about it here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation